# Fosuserbundle, custom data in register form not getting saved to databse

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am new to symfony2, I installed fosuserbundle and added a custom field to registration form. Form is getting submitted correctly but custom field data is not getting saved in database.

**RegistrationFormType.php**

```
    <?php

    namespace madhur\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

    class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            // add your custom field
            $builder->add('name');
        }

        public function getParent()
        {
            return 'fos_user_registration';
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'madhur_user_registration';
        }
    }
```

**User.php Entity**

```
    namespace madhur\DemoBundle\Entity;

    use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


    /**
     * User
     */
    class User extends BaseUser
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            // your own logic
        }

         /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         *
         * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
         * @Assert\Length(
         *     min=3,
         *     max="255",
         *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
         *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
         *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
         * )
         */
        protected $name;

        public function getName() {
         return $this->name;
        }

        public function setName($name) {
         $this->name= $name;
        }
    }
```

**config.yml**

```
    fos_user:
        db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
        firewall_name: main
        user_class: madhur\DemoBundle\Entity\User
        registration:
            form:
                type: madhur_user_registration
```

**service.yml**

```
    madhur_user.registration.form.type:
           class: madhur\DemoBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
           tags:
               - { name: form.type, alias: madhur_user_registration }
```

**User.orm.yml**

```
    madhur\DemoBundle\Entity\User:
        type:  entity
        table: fos_user
        id:
            id:
                type: integer
                generator:
                    strategy: AUTO
        fields:

            name:
                type: string
                length: 255
```

Please help!!

Comment: Where's `@ORM\Table` annotation? Let us see your controller.

Comment: @ORM\Table annotation was somehow not working so I used User.orm.yml, I have added the file code in question. Controller is default, have changed nothing there

Comment: Look good. Are you in the dev environment?

Comment: I am using on localhost, lamp

Answer (score 1):

At this late hour i don't see anything wrong in your code.
Did you update your database schema and did you clear the cache?

app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
app/console cache:clear
app/console cache:clear --env=prod